ControlWidget not appearing in control center
I am trying to show my ControlWidget in control center for iOS 18 beta 2 but it is not appearing in when I am trying to add it. My intents are appearing in shortcuts etc but they are not appearing in control center.
here is my code:
@available(iOS 18.0, *)
struct MyControlWidget: ControlWidget {
    let kind = "MyControlWidget"
    
    var body: some ControlWidgetConfiguration {
        AppIntentControlConfiguration(
            kind: kind,
            intent: MyIntent.self
        ) { configuration in
            ControlWidgetButton (action: configuration) {
                Image (systemName: "pencil")
                Text (configuration.target.name ?? "Test")
            }
        }
    }
}

@available(iOS 18.0, *)
extension MyIntent: ControlConfigurationIntent {}


Since no other answers, I hope you did list MyControlWidget in the WidgetBundle.

Once you have created a ControlWidget, you need to add it to WidgetBundle in  your WidgetExtension. Here's a sample code for it
@main
struct AppWidgetBundle: WidgetBundle {
    @WidgetBundleBuilder
    var body: some Widget {
        //any of your other widgets go here
        //below if condition is required if your deployment target is below 18, else you can remove it
        if #available(iOS 18, *) {
            MyControlWidget()
        }
    }
}

